# Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

There are 3 arrays in my PHP, $console, $model, and $game.

Here is the code by the way:

```
<?PHP
    $console = array();
    $model = array();
    $game = array();

    $gameQuery = "SELECT * FROM consoleGame";
    $gameResult = mysql_query($gameQuery) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($gameResult)) {
        if(!is_array($game[$row['modelId']])) {
            $game[$row['modelId']] = array();
        }

         $game[$row['modelId']][$row['gameId']] = array(
                                        'Game Name' => $row['gameName'],
                                        'Game ID' => $row['gameId']);
    }

    $modelQuery = "SELECT * FROM consoleModel";
    $modelResult = mysql_query($modelQuery) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($modelResult)) {
        if (!is_array($model[$row['consoleId']])) {
            $model[$row['consoleId']] = array();
        }

        $model[$row['consoleId']][$row['modelId']] = array(
                                        'Model Name' => $row['modelName'],
                                        'Model ID' => array_values($game[$row['modelId']])); //This is the warning by the way.
    }

    $consoleQuery = "SELECT * FROM consoleConsole";
    $consoleResult = mysql_query($consoleQuery) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consoleResult)) {
        if (!is_array($console[$row['consoleId']])) {
            $console[$row['consoleId']] = array();
        }

        $console[$row['consoleId']] = array(
                                        'Console Name' => $row['consoleName'],
                                        'Console ID' => array_values($model[$row['consoleId']]));
    }

    $console = array_values($console);
    echo json_encode($console);
?>
```

As you can see in the code, I have added array_values to $console and $model without a hitch. I was lucky back then. When I added array_values to $game, it creates a warning. What is the possible fix to this?

**Additional information**
I declared `$console`, `$model` and `$game` as an `array()`. I have no idea why it's not shown above `$gameQuery`.

Comment: Your array is null meaning it's not an array, it's a null value

Comment: The fix is to give an array instead of `null`. The warning is written in English and tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: What line does the warning refer to?

Comment: `mysql_query` should **not** be used in new application code because it will be removed in future versions of PHP. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: `'Model ID' => array_values($game[$row['modelId']]));` is the warning.

Comment: @tadman yes I am aware, this is just an example and for personal use.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @h2ooooooo thank you so much for the concern. I will be heading to MySQLi if you'll ask me but after if I figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using three different queries to get results from your database, and although you 'check' if a key is present for the 'modelId' in the $game array, it is possible that no game exists for a specific model;

This line guarantees that a key is added to the **$game** array if that modelId was not yet present

```
if(!is_array($game[$row['modelId']])) {
    $game[$row['modelId']] = array();
}
```

However, in the second loop, with results from `SELECT * FROM consoleModel` your loading *all* models, possibly some have no games in your database, so there won't be a key for that modelId in the $game array.

For example:

consoleGame

```
gameName | gameId | modelId
GameA    | 1      | 1
GameB    | 2      | 1
```

consoleModel

```
modelName| modelId
ModelA   | 1
ModelB   | 2
```

This will have 2 games for ModelA, but none for ModelB.

You may work around this issue by adding this inside the `$modelResult` loop too

```
if (!is_array($model[$row['consoleId']])) {
    $game[$row['modelId']] = array();
}
```

### Some ideas

The way you're collecting the data doesn't really use the 'power' of the database. Databases are designed to retrieve data *and related data* (hence the name 'relational database')

For example, to collect all consoleModels, including the games for that model (if any) use this;

```
SELECT
   consoleModel.modelId,
   consoleModel.modelName,
   consoleGame.gameId,
   consoleGame.gameName
FROM
    consoleModel
    -- Using 'LEFT' join so that consoleModels without games will also be returned
    LEFT JOIN consoleGame
      ON consoleGame.modelId = consoleModel.modelId
```

Which will return;

```
modelId | modelName | gameId | gameName
1       | ModelA    | 1      | GameA
1       | ModelA    | 1      | GameA
2       | ModelB    | NULL   | NULL
```

Although this will duplicate the ModelName rows, it may make things easier for you, as you won't have to run 3 separate loops.

Mode optimized options will be possible (e.g. loop through all consoleModels in PHP and collect the related games inside the loop), I will leave that up to you to try and learn

Comment: What about `consoleConsole` table?

Comment: @jahm I'll leave that for you to try and figure that out. The queries were just for illustrational purposes, to get you interested in options that a database can offer. I think my answer above the 'some ideas' is a resolution for your problem. Regarding the queries; try learning a bit about SQL queries (lots of info on the internet), if you have a question after trying some things, post a new question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

At first declare your $game as an array before using it such as $game = array() then please let us know where you are going to add array_value to $game

second you can use is_array($game) before adding it to array_values that is it array or not

Comment: Sorry I forgot to point out where the warning is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be defining your `$console` as an array in the firat place. Add `$console = array()` somewhere near the beginning.

Comment: `$console`, `$model` and `$game` are all arrays. I declared it before `$gameQuery` and for some reason it is not showing.

Comment: thank you for editing. I have no idea why it's not showing.

Comment: Because you need to put a blank line before starting a code block.